# Convert excel formula to Postgresql query

Tags: excel, postgresql

I have this excel formula which contain values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieoYt.png)

```
STUDENT NAME    START DATE  TEACHER NAME
X   01/01/2023  A
Y   17/02/2023  A
Z   20/03/2023  A
R   01/01/2023  B
S   17/02/2023  B
T   20/03/2023  B
```

```
DISPATCH DATE   TEACHER NAME
09/03/2023  A
26/01/2023  A
24/02/2023  A
09/03/2023  A
25/03/2023  A
24/03/2023  A
09/03/2023  B
24/03/2023  B
```

Can someone convert this formula?

```
=FILTER(A:A,C:C=G3,B:B<>"", B:B=MAX(FILTER(B:B,C:C=G3,B:B<>"",B:B<=F3)))
```

How to join to get the name of the student in a certain time range in PostgreSQL

I've tried using a regular join but the result is still a double or an error.

The correct results should be

```
STUDENT NAME
Y
X
Y
Y
Z
Z
S
T
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Excel Formula you've shared,

Filtering the values in column A based on the following conditions:

```
Column C should have a value equal to G3
Column B should not be empty/null
Column B should have a value less than or equal to F3
Column B should have the maximum value among the values in column B that meet the first three conditions
```

This is an equivalent SQL logic,

```
SELECT A
FROM postgres_table
WHERE C = 'G3' 
  AND B <> '' 
  AND B <= 'F3'
  AND B = (SELECT MAX(B) 
           FROM postgres_table
           WHERE C = 'G3' 
           AND B <> '' 
           AND B <= 'F3')
```

replace `postgres_table` with the actual table name and Let me know if this works.